# Capistranoを用いてAWS EC2へRailsアプリをデプロイ時、SSHの認証エラーが出てデプロイできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, ssh, amazon-ec2, capistrano

#### 実現したいこと

ローカルのDockerコンテナ内に作成したRailsアプリを、Capistranoを用いてAWSのEC2サーバにデプロイしたいです。

#### 表示されているエラー

dockerのRailsコンテナ内で「bundle exec cap production deploy」すると、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ec2-user@(IPアドレス): Authentication failed for user ec2-user@(IPアドレス)
```

全文
[image: エラー内容]

#### 困っていること

エラー内容から、SSHの鍵の問題かと推測し調査中です。
推測される原因や解決方法をご教示いただきたいと考えています。

#### 現状のCapistrano設定ファイル

#### Capfile

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"

require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# add requires
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/puma'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

#### config/deploy.rb

```
lock "3.7.0"

# Capistranoのログの表示に利用する
set :application, "myfavrest-app"

# どのリポジトリからアプリをpullするかを指定する
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:gcp632dsh/myfavrest-app.git"

# サーバ上でのソースの配置先
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/apps/myapp"

# Rubyをrbenv経由で使う
set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_ruby, File.read('.ruby-version').strip
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"

# アプリケーションで使用するgemをリリース間で共有
append :linked_dirs, '.bundle'

# サーバの並列数
set :bundle_jobs, 2

# リリース間での共有リソース定義
append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets"
```

#### config/deploy/production.rb

```
# EC2サーバーのIP、EC2サーバーにログインするユーザー名、サーバーのロールを記述
server '(IPアドレス)', user: 'ec2-user', roles: %w{app db web} 

set :ssh_options, {
  # capistranoコマンド実行者の秘密鍵
  keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa),
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w(publickey)
}
```

#### Gemfile（関連部分のみ抜粋）

```
ruby '2.6.5'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv-vars'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
end
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    environment:
       （省略）
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/rails/Dockerfile
    command: bundle exec pumactl start
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - public-data:/myapp/public
      - tmp-data:/myapp/tmp
      - log-data:/myapp/log
      - sockets:/myapp/tmp/sockets
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - db
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - public-data:/myapp/public
      - tmp-data:/myapp/tmp
      - sockets:/myapp/tmp/sockets
    depends_on: 
      - app
volumes:
  db-volume:
  public-data:
  tmp-data:
  log-data:
  sockets:
```

#### 参考にした情報・試したこと

Capistranoの設定は下記記事を参照しました。
[Capistrano 3によるRails 5.2 + puma + nginxのデプロイをステップバイステップで学ぶ](https://qiita.com/tkykmw/items/a34441aae142e0e41b65)

また、エラー内容から推測し、鍵の設定の問題かと思い、下記の記事を参照して、
deploy/production.rbの:ssh_optionsの箇所を修正し、再びデプロイ実行しましたがエラー内容は変わらずでした。
[capistranoでデプロイする時のssh-key周りのTips](https://qiita.com/Takkiii/items/c4f2cfd143e97e061e66)
→この記事における、**「これだけだとgithubからソースコードを取ってこれないのでgithubの方にも自分の公開鍵を置く必要がある。さらに自分のssh-keyをssh-agentで使用する場合は以下のコマンドをローカル環境で実行する必要がある。」**という文章は、具体的に何の操作をすればいいのか、全くわからず何も出来ていない状態です。。

「どこの何の鍵を、どこに置けばいいのか？」
「何かの鍵を新しく生成する必要があるのか？」
等、混乱しており、少しずつ調べているところです。

SSHクライアント（Rlogin）を通じて、EC2にはSSH接続できており（EIPで固定IP化もしています）
var/www/app/myappというデプロイ用ディレクトリも作成しています。

#### 環境

Ruby 2.6.5
Rails 5.2.4
puma 3.11
EC2のAMIはAmazon Linux 2 (t2.micro)
ホストOS：Windows10 Home
Virtual Box上にDocker-composeを使ってコンテナを構築しており、そちらは問題なく動いており、アプリにもブラウザでアクセスできます。（Puma(Rails)+Nginx+Mysqlのコンテナがそれぞれ存在）

なお、こちらの質問は、恐れ入りますがteratailでも質問中です。
https://teratail.com/questions/278675
teratailでもし情報アップデートありましたら、すぐこちらにも反映させていただきます。

不明点、不足情報等ございましたら、お手数をお掛けし恐縮ですがご教示いただけますと幸いです。
継続して鍵のことについて勉強・調査中ですが、皆さんのお力添え頂きたく、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
ローカル側の.sshディレクトリと秘密鍵の権限が過剰でした。
.sshディレクトリは700（drwx------）、秘密鍵については600または400にすべきでした。

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/myportfolio-ssh-key.pem
```

[SSHでPermission deniedがでたら](https://hacknote.jp/archives/2225/)

鍵の権限が過剰であるといけないということを知りませんでした。
dockerコンテナ上の.sshディレクトリに秘密鍵を置き、権限を上記設定したところ、SSHのエラーが解消されることが確認できました。